# Bash History Under OS X (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks, command-history

Why does my bash history under OS X never seem to persist for more than an hour or two (or a day, at most)?

Comment: What values do you have for your HIST* variables? `set | grep ^HIST` -- I suspect your HISTSIZE is too low. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities

Comment: HISTFILESIZE=500; HISTSIZE=500; My HISTSIZE only appears to be about half of my Ubuntu value, so it doesn't seem like it should be so useless. My sweet-spot must be somewhere in between, such that I don't notice when under Ubuntu.